# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am trying to install this maven project on eclipse. While trying to do so I keep getting this error (I'll paste the error below). I went online to look for solutions and read a few articles related to it but almost all of those suggested either of the following,

> - reinstall the project after deleting the .m2 folder or
> - update my maven to the latest version.

But none of this is working for me as the error appears every time I try to install it and I am already on maven 3.6.3

- OS: windows 10.
- JDK: 1.8.0_45
- Maven: 3.6.3
- IDE tested on: Eclipse JEE 2020-06

The error:

```
F:\SVN\mocollege>mvn clean install -U
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.stl.moschool:mocollege >---------------------
[INFO] Building mocollege 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ mocollege ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mocollege ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenResourcesFiltering was bound.
 while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo

1 error
   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException (InternalProvisionException.java:226)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1053)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
   at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
   at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
   at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
   at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
   at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
   at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
   at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
   at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
   at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.734 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-21T18:13:02+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project mocollege: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Unable to load the mojo 'resources' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenResourcesFiltering was bound.
[ERROR]   while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo
[ERROR]   at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR]   while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR]       role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR]   roleHint: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

The pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stl.moschool</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>mocollege</name>
  <description>mocollege</description>
  <artifactId>mocollege</artifactId>
  
  <properties>
  <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  
  <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>
        
        <!-- Spring -->
        <!-- <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>3.1.3 -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <springframework-orm-version>4.2.1.RELEASE</springframework-orm-version>
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <!-- Database Driver -->
        <postgres-jdbc4.version>9.0-801.jdbc4</postgres-jdbc4.version>
        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
        <apachetiles.version>2.2.1</apachetiles.version>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
        <!-- Apache commons file upload -->
        <commons-file-upload.version>1.3.1</commons-file-upload.version>
        <!-- Apache commons dbcp  -->
        <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>     
        <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
  
  </properties>
  
  
  <dependencies>
    
        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Added after common-digester error -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
    
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
                
        <!-- For json conversion -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added by lusi on Dt-26-10-2017 -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Form Validation using Annotations -->  
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- importing lambok  -->
        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
               <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
               <version>1.16.16</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- <dependency>
               <groupId>cc.ccutil</groupId>
               <artifactId>ccavutil</artifactId>
               <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added by lusi on Dt-26-10-2017 end -->
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-el</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Database Driver -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgres-jdbc4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- File Upload -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-file-upload.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add by lusi on Dt-26-10-2017 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add end -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
           <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
           <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.49</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.49</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Form Validation using Annotations -->  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jmimemagic</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmimemagic</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>         
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>         
         <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>         
         <version>7.0.2</version>     
      </dependency>  
      
      <dependency>         
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>         
         <artifactId>io</artifactId>         
         <version>7.0.2</version>     
      </dependency>  
      
      <dependency>         
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>         
         <artifactId>layout</artifactId>         
         <version>7.0.2</version>
      </dependency>  
      
      <dependency>         
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>         
         <artifactId>forms</artifactId>         
         <version>7.0.2</version>    
      </dependency>  
      
      <dependency>         
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>         
         <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>         
         <version>7.0.2</version>     
      </dependency>  
      
      <dependency>         
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>         
         <artifactId>sign</artifactId>         
         <version>7.0.2</version>     
      </dependency>  
      
      <dependency>         
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>         
         <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>         
         <version>7.0.2</version>     
      </dependency>  
      
      <dependency>         
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>         
         <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>         
         <version>7.0.2</version>     
      </dependency>  
      
      <dependency>         
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>         
         <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>         
         <version>7.0.2</version>    
      </dependency> 
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies> 
    
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            
            <!-- For Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>-->
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <path>/mocollege</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                      
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

Any sort of help or insight is much appreciated.

-Thank you

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/732806/maven/build-tools/Failed-execute-goal-org-apache#3408577

Comment: I have my doubts that you are on Maven: 4.0.0 ?

Comment: Yeah I checked the maven version by running mvn -version and got 3.6.3. But still I don't think that's causing the issue. @khmarbaise